# Sewing thread holder

Tags: particles

How can i an make an object like this:
[image: Sewing thread]

I only interested on how to get the woven sewing thread effect.
Nodes tend to give a bad flat look. And i have no idea how to create something like this with modeling.

I was only able to create this with the use of a texture:

[image: cgi spool]

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? Please show you current progress. Just so it's less of a tutorial request :).

Comment: I agree. 
Also: Your texture is very coarse, the threads have a much larger diameter than on the reference. It's going to be tough to do this with a normal map alone, because the structure is so fine. As a pointer: Use tangent maps in combination with an anisotropic material.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz i was wondering wether it could be done as actual geometry instead of normal map

Comment: it could. But render it in the winter, so you don't have to use a radiator that week. Kidding. But this is exactly the kind of thing you use normal maps and other textures for.

Comment: if you really want to you can use a displacement modifier with a texture and just add a whole lot of subdivisions, tho as Frederik Steinmetz said this is the perfect thing to use a normal/bump map with